# Why does Room require you to list out entities?

Tags: android-room

Just curious if anyone knows why Room requires you to list out each entity.  Why can't it automatically find all of your entities with the @Entity annotation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you can have more than a single database in a project, Room needs to know which classes are used by which DB.

By declaring the Entities in the DB class you are actually building a hierarchy that informs the compiler which classes to use to produce the wanted result from the DAO.

In theory, your argument does have a point as in cases of a single DB or where there are multi DB but no overlaps there should not be a problem but to prevent overlaps and for clarity sake, they demand that you declare everything.

Comment: Thanks.  It still seems like they should be able to handle multi DB and overlap by letting you specify which database(s) an entity belongs to in the Entity annotation.